# Apply different margins on images in a single div

Tags: html, css

Please consider the jsfiddle demo where I've laid out 7 cards with transform effects.
Now I would like to apply a different margin to individual images such that the card2 is for example 15px lower, card3 is 5px higher etc.

However, when I apply for example `margin-top: 15px` to card2, all cards in the div are rendered with `margin-top: 15px`

Another issue is that the centered div is not really centered when applying width: 100% to it.

```
<div class="centered">
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2r7x1ch.jpg" class="card1" />
    <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2r7x1ch.jpg" class="card2" />
    <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2r7x1ch.jpg" class="card3" />
    <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2r7x1ch.jpg" class="card4" />
    <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2r7x1ch.jpg" class="card5" />
    <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2r7x1ch.jpg" class="card6" />
    <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2r7x1ch.jpg" class="card7" />
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kristofvhren/wtDE4/

Comment: try position relative and display block?

Comment: Played dirty at first place right? Why not paste your code when system is throwing you a message to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Remove `inline-block` property from images and use

```
img {
    width: 125px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

instead..

Answer (score 1):

Use 'float:left' property in 'img' tag and you can use margin in '.card2'